# Prove that three points are collinear using their corresponding vectors.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, vectors

Let $a = \begin{pmatrix}x_a\\y_a\\z_a\end{pmatrix}$, $b = \begin{pmatrix}x_b\\y_b\\z_b\end{pmatrix}$, and $c = \begin{pmatrix}x_c\\y_c\\z_c\end{pmatrix}$.
Show that $(x_a,y_a,z_a)$, $(x_b,y_b,z_b)$, and $(x_c,y_c,z_c)$ are collinear if and only if
$$a \times b + b \times c + c \times a = 0.$$

---

I was thinking of proving that the area of the triangle formed by the three points is 0.  I thought the box product, $|(a \times b)\bullet c|$, would be helpful but I don't know how to relate that to the equation.  All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why delete and repost the [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210960/prove-that-three-3-d-points-are-collinear-using-3-d-vectors)? You should edit the first post if you need to add or make changes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to complicate this problem. We know that $x\times y=0$ if and only if $x=my$ where $m$ is a real number. Given $a$, $b$, $c$, we want to look at $a-b$ and $b-c$
$$(a-b)\times(b-c)=a\times b - a\times c -b\times b +b\times c=a\times b +b\times c+c\times a$$
If $a$,$b$, $c$ are collinear, then the left hand side is 0, therefore the right hand side is 0. Or the other way around, if RHS=0 then LHS=0, therefore $(a-b)=m(b-c)$.

Comment: How does $(a-b)\times(b-c) = 0 \iff (a-b) = m(b-c)$ imply that $a\parallel b, \;a\parallel c, $ and $b\parallel c$ exactly?

Comment: $a$ is not parallel to $b$ or to $c$. The difference between two pairs have to be parallel.  If you think in a plane (1,0),(1,1), and (1,-1) are not parallel, but they represent point on a vertical line through $x=1$

Comment: I agree with you now, after I saw geometrical justification [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1339287/229317)