# How to prove this condition if three vectors are colinear?

Tags: vectors

So I was given this problem:

> Let $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}x_a\\y_a\\z_a\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}x_b\\y_b\\z_b\end{pmatrix}$, and $\vec{c} = \begin{pmatrix}x_c\\y_c\\z_c\end{pmatrix}$.
>   Show that $(x_a,y_a,z_a)$, $(x_b,y_b,z_b)$, and $(x_c,y_c,z_c)$ are collinear if and only if
>   $$\vec{a} \times \vec{b} + \vec{b} \times \vec{c} + \vec{c} \times \vec{a} = \mathbf{0}.$$

I tried plugging it in and it looks like it is true:

> Let $\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\6\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix}4\\8\\12\end{pmatrix}$, and $\vec{c} = \begin{pmatrix}8\\16\\24\end{pmatrix}$.
>   $$\vec{a} \times \vec{b} + \vec{b} \times \vec{c} + \vec{c} \times \vec{a}
> =\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
>  +\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
>  +\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
> =
> \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
> $$

How could I prove this to be true? I am not entirely sure where to begin.

Comment: Your example of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are not collinear.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks @Fimpellizieri

Comment: I replied earlier today to a similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211073/prove-that-three-points-are-collinear-using-their-corresponding-vectors/2211106#2211106

Comment: @Andrei This same question has been posted *twice* before in the past few hours, for some odd reason (first one deleted since). It's a duplicate of an old question, anyway, and I voted to close as such.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1339242/265466.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $|v \times w| = |v||w|\sin \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$. Therefore three points $a$, $b$ and $c$ are collinear if and only 
$$(b - a) \times (c - a) = 0$$
Expanding
$$b \times c - b\times a - a \times c + a \times a = 0$$
Since $a \times a = 0$ and anticommutivity
$$a\times b +  b \times c + c \times a = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are colinear if

$$\vec{A}=k\vec{B}$$

Then the **vector product** naturally comes out to be $0$.

Comment: While the two vectors are colinear with the origin, collinearlity is in general a property involving more than two vectors on a line that lie on the same line.

Comment: @YBerman Sorry, but I seriously don't get what you are talking about. when we show that A.B are collinear and B,C are collinear then?

Comment: @YBerman If you'd be kind enough to reply.

Comment: Collinearity means "on the same line". Any two points define a line but when a third vector is on the same line, this is special. You considered the case of two points and the origin on the same line. What if the third vector is not the origin. Three arbitrary vectors that are collinear: e.g. (1,0) (0, 1) (.5,.5)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Collinear vectors have the same direction vector.

Comment: Are (1, 0), (0, 1) and (0.5, 0.5)  collinear in R^2?

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. I was thinking that vectors themselves all have the same direction. Similar reasoning as samjoe. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.